# Installing packages from an .iso file

Tags: package-management, iso, edubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a desktop system and I have an .iso file of Edubuntu 12.04, can I install Edubuntu packages in Ubuntu 12.04 from Edubuntu's iso file? That desktop system has no internet connection.

Comment: No internet connection or slow internet connection?

Comment: No internet connection..

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can do this. Here are two:

1. You can open the ISO file using the archive manager (right click on the file and select *Open With Archive Manager*). The packages are inside the `pool` directory.
2. Using the terminal, you can type this command:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop,ro "/path/to/the/image.iso" "/path/to/the/mount/point"
   ```

   `"/path/to/the/image.iso"` is the location of your ISO file, while `"/path/to/the/mount/point"` is the location of an empty directory. After issuing the command, you will find the ISO files inside that directory. Again, the packages are inside `pool`.

Note that the `pool` directory contains some core packages. Other packages are not shipped inside the CD nor in any installation (because this would double size it).

Comment: the packages that i need are not there in pool directory for example gocompris, kalzium, kturtle etc etc. the pool directory only has some system packages like kernel, ndiswrapper, pygtk, and wvdial etc.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. I've updated the question with the answer. If you really need those packages, you ought to create an ad-hoc CD (or some other device) from a computer with an Internet connection.

Comment: Is there some way to hook things up such that the usual commands like e.g. apt-get install foo then know where to look for the packages?

Comment: Yes: you can add a file in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` containing this line: `deb file:///path/to/the/mount/point distro main universe`, then run `apt update`